# how to specifcy bit length of binary conversion c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Wanting to convert the input from a winform textbox into one's compliment.

I have the code working for one's compliment however I'm unsure how to specifiy the bit length, so it can be displayed better.

Thanks in advance.

```
if (operatorComboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            int decimalNumber = int.Parse(inputTextBox.Text);
            int onesCompliment = ~decimalNumber;
            string binary = Convert.ToString(onesCompliment, 2);
            outputTextBox.Text = binary;
        }
```

Comment: You are using an `int`, which is signed 32-bit integer in c#.

Comment: Is your question how to specify the bit length of the variable's type  `onesCompliment` or do you want to shorten your `binary` variable's string length?